# On locally isometric surfaces and coordinate transformations?

Tags: differential-geometry

Usually to distinguish is two metrics are locally isometric we use:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%E2%80%93Karlhede_algorithm

Is this equivalent to the problem saying: given 2 line elements $ds^2$ and $dS^2$ there exists no coordinate transformation which makes $ds^2$ identical to $dS^2$? For example there is no cordinate transformation which takes the metric of a two sphere to that of flat Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: @so the answer is yes?

Comment: As I said before: coordinate transformations don't change the metric. This should answer the question in your last paragraph. Note that a map between manifolds that can/cannot be a (local) isometry is something more general than a coordinate transformation of a single manifold.

Comment: Yea thanks if you have any book recommendation for someone with a physics background to make sense of differential geometry so that they can converse with a mathematician

Comment: You have my sympathies. I don't even know  in what camp I am. Learned GR first from Sean Carroll, then MTW, now reading Nakahara as necessary. Wikipedia is not enough. A recent short but very good book is also Lugo, *Differential Geometry in Physics.* You will see just from the titles of those books that the aim should be to converse with physicists familar with those matters.